# Create a method for adding and removing from an array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, addition

I'm creating a C# class with array members that is supposed to work like a `List`.
I want something syntax that is similar to the following when adding a book to a book list.

```
book.Add(firstName = "Jack", lastName = "Reacher", title = "Dollar", year = 2005);
```

This book should now be added to an array.We keep track of all the books that we add to that array.

I also want to be able to write something like:

```
book.delete[2];
```

to delete the 3'rd book in from the array.

What would be the best way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Writing this with square brackets is not only impossible, it's also wrong. Are you sure you don't want `book.delete(2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the perspective of OOP, a better way would just be to use the Generic List as pointed out by Shahrooz Jefri - and make a custom class or struct "Book", which would have member fields "string firstName", "string lastName", "string title", and "int year."

Then, juust make a list of books like this,

```
List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
books.Add(new Book("Jack","Reacher","Dollar",2005));
```

If you need to implement your own generic collection w/ static arrays, you can do something like:

```
public class MyList<T> {
    private T[] internalArray;
    private int capacity;
    private int size;
    public int Size { get { return size; } }
    public MyList(){
        this.size = 0;
        this.capacity = 2; //put something you feel like is reasonable for initial capacity
        internalArray = new T[2];
    }
    public void Add(T item){
        int factor = 2; //some "growth" factor
        if(this.size == this.capacity){
            this.capacity *= factor;
            T[] newArray = new T[this.capacity];
            System.Array.Copy(this.internalArray, newArray, this.size);
            this.internalArray = newArray;
        }
        this.internalArray[this.size] = item;
        this.size ++;
    }
    public void RemoveAt(int index){
        //write code that shifts all elements following index  back by one
        //decrement the size
        //if necessary for mem. conservation, shrink the array capacity if half of less elements remain
    }
}
```

Off course, then you'll have to overload the [] bracket operator for access, perhaps make it implement the Enumerable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to object and for collecrion use [Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) [List](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list)

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
    list.Add(2);
    list.Add(3);
    list.Add(5);
    list.Add(7);
```

Comment: I think that the OP wants to implement a List and that this is an exercise. It's at least worth to wait until he has clarified his intent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add and remove items at will, then an array might not be the best choice. Resizing arrays is relatively expensive; it is better to use something like a list (as suggested by Shahrooz Jefri).

Also, I would shift the add/remove operation away from the book itself and towards the collection. Better to do:

```
bookList.Add(...)
```

...than...

```
book.Add(...)
```